# Getting Small UI text size on Chrome OS after Android Studio update

Tags: android-studio, editor, google-chrome-os

As compared to the previous release of android studio editor text size is small On Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, do the following:

1. Open the **Settings** window by clicking **File > Settings**
2. Navigate to **Appearance & Behavior > Appearance.**
3. Select **Use custom font**.
4. Increase the font size.
5. In the **Settings** window, navigate to **Editor > Font**.
6. Increase the font size.
7. Click **OK.**